# REGEX with preg_replace cannot match with parantheses?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Does preg_replace has collision with parentheses in image name?

Here's my code:

```
Pattern: /\/images\/upload\/image\/201808\/thumbnail(3).jpg/

Replacement: some_domain_url/images/upload/image/201808/thumbnail(3).jpg

Content: <img src="/images/upload/image/201808/thumbnail(3).jpg" alt="" />
```

Result: does not replace. I tried replacing parenthesis with %28 and %29 also does not work.

Addition: The pattern and replacements are stored in a dynamic array. It has to be replace by REGEX. The objective is to replace all local image path to a cloud storage.

Any REGEX professional can advise please?

Comment: you need to escape ALL the special characters

Comment: Addition: It works perfectly fine without parenthesis.

Comment: @IdontDownVote you mean escape (addslashes) in content or pattern or both?

Comment: you dont have to do it manully, http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: In the pattern. See the [Literal Characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) section

Comment: Thank you so much for all your advise. the problem occurs only at online testing tool. When I use brute force str_replace("(","\(",$var) and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the parentheses like so:

```
\(3\).jpg
```

Comment: i tried in "preg_replace.onlinephpfunctions.com/" with backslash, still fails.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your advise. the problem occurs only at online testing tool. When I use brute force str_replace("(","(",$var) and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, parenthesis are special characters in regex. They would need to be escaped. But you're making this more difficult than it needs to be. Just use `str_replace` since you aren't using any of the regex benefits.

```
str_replace('/images/upload/image/201808/thumbnail(3).jpg', 'some_domain_url/images/upload/image/201808/thumbnail(3).jpg', '<img src="/images/upload/image/201808/thumbnail(3).jpg" alt="" />');
```

or with an `i` if you wanted to be case insensitive:

```
str_ireplace('/images/upload/image/201808/thumbnail(3).jpg', 'some_domain_url/images/upload/image/201808/thumbnail(3).jpg', '<img src="/images/upload/image/201808/thumbnail(3).jpg" alt="" />');
```

or ... the proper long winded way:

```
$dom = new domdocument();
$dom->loadhtml('<img src="/images/upload/image/201808/thumbnail(3).jpg" alt="" />', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$imgs = $dom->getelementsbytagname('img');
if(strpos($imgs[0]->getAttribute('src'), '/images/upload/image/201808/thumbnail(3).jpg') !== FALSE) {
    $imgs[0]->setAttribute('src', 'some_domain_url' . $imgs[0]->getAttribute('src'));
    echo $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

https://3v4l.org/au5Du

Comment: sorry, the replacements and patterns are dynamic. It is contained in an array, then loop for preg_replaced. I tried multiple fail attempt to escape them in "preg_replace.onlinephpfunctions.com".

Comment: Thank you so much for your advise. the problem occurs only at online testing tool. When I use brute force str_replace("(","(",$var) and it will work. your way works too in the way of hard coded. =)

Comment: You replace a parenthesis with a parenthesis?? How does that do anything different?